# SWIFT - UIImage(contentsOfFile: "") SLOWER than UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "") WHY?

Tags: swift, performance, uiimage, cpu, draw

**Faced with a strange issue when UIImage(contentsOfFile: "") SLOWER than UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "")**

In my CALayer I have ONE global variable

```
let img:UIImage? = nil
```

...and If the viewDidLoad I'm loading img using "**contentsOfFile**", then it draw this image very SLOW. (For example during touchMove+refresh CPU under 99-100% and FPS 5-10)

```
img = UIImage(cgImage: UIImage(contentsOfFile: controlPath! + "/line.png")!.cgImage!, scale: 2.0, orientation: UIImage.Orientation.up)
```

But... if in the viewDidLoad I'm loading the same img using "**imageLiteralResourceName**" or UIImage(data:NSDATA) - then it works Perfect! CPU load is low, FPS40-60 WHY???

```
img = UIImage(cgImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "line.png").cgImage!, scale: 2.0, orientation: UIImage.Orientation.up).cgImage
```

**Code that draw 100 copies of this image on screen:**

```
override public func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
...

   //here we draw this image... nothing special
   for _ in 0...99{
      ctx.draw(img.cgImage!, in: randomPositionRect)
   }

...
}
```

refreshing screen:

```
  override public func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    ....

    myLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

> **PS> in objective c it work fast in both cases. Issue only with SWIFT**

Full draw code:

```
var value = self.frame.size.height/2.0  //this value is changing in touchMove

override public func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {

    let height:CGFloat = self.frame.size.height-paddingTop!-paddingBottom!

    //rotate screen
    ctx.translateBy(x: +(frame.size.width / 2), y: +(frame.size.height / 2))
    ctx.rotate(by: degreesToRadians(x: 180))
    ctx.scaleBy(x: -1.0, y: 1.0)
    ctx.translateBy(x: -(frame.size.width / 2), y: -(frame.size.height / 2))

    ////
    ctx.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: 110)

    //Define the degrees needed for each plane to create a circle
    let degForPlane = Float(360.0 / CGFloat(panelsCount!))
    let radius: CGFloat = height / 2.0


    //The current angle offset (initially it is 0... it will change through the pan function)
    let vv: CGFloat = ((160.0 / frame.size.height) * (self.value)) + 10
    var degX: CGFloat = vv
    degX -= 90
    degX += 360

    /////DRAW Carousel ////

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0 - (originalPanelSize!.height / 2.0), width: originalPanelSize!.width, height: originalPanelSize!.height)

    for i in 0...panelsCount!-1 {

        //Create the Matrix identity
        var t: CATransform3D = CATransform3DIdentity

        //Perform rotate on the matrix identity
        t = CATransform3DRotate(t, degreesToRadians(x: degX), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

        //Perform translate on the current transform matrix (identity + rotate)
        t = CATransform3DTranslate(t, 0.0, 0.0, radius)

        if i > -1 && ((degX >= -180 && degX <= 90) || (degX >= 270 && degX <= 450)) {
            let affine = CGAffineTransform(a: t.m11, b: t.m12, c: t.m21, d: t.m22, tx: t.m41, ty: t.m42)

            ctx.saveGState()
            ctx.concatenate(affine)


            ctx.draw(img!, in: rect)

            ctx.restoreGState()

        }

        degX -= CGFloat(degForPlane)

    }
}
```

[image: Fast Case]
[image: Slow Case]

Comment: Please, show the whole drawing code. If you are loading images inside the `draw` function then you are doing it wrong. There is no need to access `CGImage` to draw the image either. Also note that is not likely that both methods load the same image since `contentsOfFile:` won't actually load the image with the correct scale.

Comment: No problem. Added full ctx.draw code.  I'm loading img in the viewDidLoad()

Comment: Could you please check `img.scale` in both cases? Is it the same?

Comment: I would also recommend to use `UIGraphicsPushContext` & `UIGraphicsPopContext` and then use `UIImage.draw` instead of accessing the `CGImage` because that can have serious performance implications.

Comment: Yes, I even tried scale 1.0, but nothing... Also just for experiment I tried to use this functions directly in the func draw. And with "imageLiteralResourceName" it still works fast, like nothing changed - 50-60 fps. But when used "contentsOfFile" it almost did not draw, it's like 2-5 fps. In the viewDidLoad it was maybe 5-10fps.   it seems to me in the first case it loads image into memory, and in the second it reads from the disk every time

Comment: `UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName:)` and `UIImage(named:)` are both caching loaded images therefore loading with them should be always faster the second time.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But you can see my GIF animations that I attached.  BTW with "objective c" everything works fast in both cases. I started rewriting my application on swift and spent 3 days to find the problem why a simple and the same code slows down)) and on the last 13inch ipad it loads the processor under 100% during self.setNeedsDisplay, although on objective c, no graphics issues and cpu just almost 5-14%

Comment: I am afraid I don't really trust the Objective-C vs Swift comparison since the used API is both written in Objective-C. It's hard to help since we don't have a way to actually reproduce that. Could you maybe compile a minimum reproducible sample on github?

Comment: Created - https://github.com/Wiksnet/UIImage-Slow-Fast-Example

Comment: Interesting, so far I see no difference between the two methods. What Xcode and iOS version do you have?

Comment: XCode Version 10.1 (10B61).  I tested on iPad Air (seems iPad4 or 5) with iOS 12.1.1  You may not notice on modern devices like iphone x or iPad Pro 13 inch, but the CPU will be very large. I not checked on iPad 3 but I think it will be very slow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187492/discussion-between-user1195202-and-sulthan).

Answer (score -1):

My current solution for now to use custom extension that load image by NSData:

Create a file UIImage+ext.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIImage{

static func fromFile (path:String)->UIImage? {

    if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
        return UIImage(cgImage: UIImage(data: data as Data)!.cgImage!, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: UIImage.Orientation.up)
    }

    return nil
}
```

}

Use:

```
let img = UIImage.fromFile(path: "MyFoler1/MyFolder2/File.png")
```

Comment: Why do you convert `UIImage` to `cgImage` just to be immediately converted to `UIImage`?

Comment: otherwise, image on the screens with retina will look very poor. And scale will be 1.0 instead of 2.0.

Comment: You may set scale as second parameter: [init(data:scale:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624109-init)

Comment: Or, you may just add `@2x` to the image file names. Or put images to `Assets.xcassets` and set their scale there.

Comment: thanks, I'll try data:scale.  @2x I'm not using because app will take a more space if use two files

Comment: What? Just take the files you have and just add `@2x`. Not add 2 more files, just change names of those existing. If you're specifying `scale: 2.0` everywhere, they're definitely are `@2x` images. Just let system to know it, instead of letting it to think it's `@1x` and then manually rescale it.